# Updating a empty column based on another column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014

I have a table `point` with the following (sample) data:

```
datekey pointkey  filter_key  t_key                            
-----------------------------------
  (5506061, 37, NULL, 1),
(5506061, 37, NULL, 1),
(5506061, 37, NULL, 1),
(5506061, 37, NULL, 1),
(5506061, 37, NULL, 1),
(5506061, 37, NULL, 1),
(5506763, 37, NULL, 2),
(5506763, 37, NULL, 2),
(5506763, 37, NULL, 2),
(45643, 97, NULL, 2),
(45643, 97, NULL, 2),
(45643, 97, NULL, 2),
(45643, 97, NULL, 2),
(45643, 97, NULL, 2),
(45643, 97, NULL, 2),
(1234, 83, NULL, 1),
(1234, 83, NULL, 1),
(1234, 83, NULL, 1),
(1234, 83, NULL, 1),
(1234, 83, NULL, 1),
(1234, 83, NULL, 1),
(1234, 84, NULL, 1),
(1234, 84, NULL, 1),
(1234, 84, NULL, 1),
(1234, 84, NULL, 1),
(1234, 84, NULL, 1),
(1234, 84, NULL, 1),
(45645, 97, NULL, 1),
(45645, 97, NULL, 2),
(45645, 97, NULL, 2),
(45645, 97, NULL, 2),
(45645, 97, NULL, 2),
(45645, 97, NULL, 2)
```

The combination of the rows above can be same 1-6 times. With that I mean like the first 6 rows in the example above. There is no unique key in this table.This table has a couple of million rows like above.

I want to UPDATE this table to fill the NULL column (filter_key). In this column I want the values 1 and 2. When its a '2' in the t_key column the 2 must be also in the filter_key column. When its a 1 in the t_key column I only want the '1' once in the in the first record, all other columns must be '2'.

So the mentioned code above must be transfered into:

```
5506061 37        1        1
5506061 37        2        1
5506061 37        2        1
5506061 37        2        1
5506061 37        2        1
5506061 37        2        1
5506763 37        2        2
5506763 37        2        2
5506763 37        2        2
45643   97        2        2
45643   97        2        2
45643   97        2        2
45643   97        2        2
45643   97        2        2
45643   97        2        2
1234    83        1        1
1234    83        2        1
1234    83        2        1
1234    83        2        1
1234    83        2        1
1234    83        2        1
1234    84        1        1
1234    84        2        1
1234    84        2        1
1234    84        2        1
1234    84        2        1
1234    84        2        1
45645   97        1        1
45645   97        2        2
45645   97        2        2
45645   97        2        2
45645   97        2        2
45645   97        2        2
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: What should happen when `t_key` is `3` or anything other than `1` or `2`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ms sql server 2014

Comment: @Prdp This column can only be a '1' or '2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `Row_Number` and `CASE` statement

***'1' once in the in the first record***  to find the first record I have ordered the result with `datekey,pointkey` columns if you want to order the result using some other column then use that in `Order by`

```
SELECT datekey,
       pointkey,
       CASE WHEN t_key = 1 AND Row_number()OVER(Partition by datekey,pointkey ORDER BY (select null)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS filter_key,
       t_key
FROM   Yourtable
```

If the result from above query is good enough then run the below update query

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT datekey,
       pointkey,
       filter_key,
       CASE WHEN t_key = 1 AND Row_number()OVER(Partition by datekey,pointkey ORDER BY (select null)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS new_filter_key,
       t_key
FROM   Yourtable  
)
update cte set filter_key = new_filter_key
```

- [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/NUB29580)

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to rextester - at last an online testing platform that I can work from my android phone! When playing around there I also managed to shorten your beautiful answer a bit further: `UPDATE t SET filter_key = new_filter_key
FROM ( SELECT filter_key,
       CASE WHEN t_key = 1 AND Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY datekey,pointkey) = 1 
            THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS new_filter_key
       FROM #Table1 ) t;
SELECT * FROM #table1`

Comment: @cars10 - Glad it is useful to you :)  Yeah derived table update looks simple as well

Comment: Ty for your answer @Prdp! The result im getting is that every filter_key row returns as '2'

Comment: @sql123 - Did you check the demo ? It is not case

Comment: @Prdp - I know its weird. I see your demo and it works. But when I try it on my table it doenst work (I tried three times).

Comment: @sql123 - So you are missing something either in sample data or logic you have explained

Comment: @Prdp - If u want I can send u my table?

Comment: @sql123 - Not just the table, result as well for the data in your table .

Comment: @Prdp -  How can I sent this to u?

Comment: @sql123 - How many records are present in your table. You can add that in question itself. Try to add the records in which you are seeing wrong results

Comment: @Prdp -  There are like 10 million rows in this table. Just 5300 have a '1' at the t_key column.

Comment: @sql123 - am sure out of `5300` records with `'1'` in `t_key` there will be one record with `1` in `filter_key`

Comment: No, every filter_key returns with '2'

Comment: @sql123 -  `select * from Yourtable where t_key = 1`  run this and tell me if it returns any record

Comment: @Pdrp - it returns 5305 rows

Comment: @sql123 - Updated my answer. You need to `partition by datekey`. Updated demo as well

Comment: @Prdp -  Thanks for your asnwer. It still doenst work but I think I know what the problem is. Please try the sample data I posted and try again. Look at row 20 after the update.

Comment: @Pdrp - not row 20 but 22

Comment: @sql123 You need to `partition by datekey,pointkey`. updated answer and demo check now

Comment: @Prdp - It works now! Thanks for your help and time!